# Issue with HTML email signature in reply

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm having issues with an email signature I'm creating with HTML. I've linked an image from another topic (dated 2013), with the same issue - to no fix.

When replying to an email, the quoted text appears beside the signature, instead of underneath. I've tried 100% width on numerous elements, to the same issue. Breaks also don't work (trimmed in Outlook?).

I've created the signature with tables. Formatting the html doc in Word (setting table word wrap to none) will fix the issue - but I don't want the mass amounts of fluff associated with the Word created html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Source Topic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/87291bcc-5035-4f4d-a23e-314b380ff2ac/outlook-2003-email-signature-formatting-problem-when-relpying?forum=outlook)

[image]

Edit: Fixed - I had to nest tables. Surrounded my signature table with a `<table><tr><td width="100%"> ... </tr></td></table>`

Comment: how are you adding the HTML signature in your outlook?

Comment: I've tried both via copy/paste and editing the file created by Outlook in AppData

Comment: If you are using outlook 2010 there is an option to add a signature.. I can add the image but in that case I've post the image with answer.

Comment: Adding the signature isn't an issue. It'll work perfectly when creating a new email...  only when I try replying to someone, will I have issues. The quoted text in the reply will come up BESIDE my signature, rather than below it. I can press enter 6-7 times to move the quoted text down, but this isn't ideal :(

Comment: can you post a picture how you add a signature code?

Comment: I can't sorry. I don't have Outlook, myself - but I am creating the signature for someone that does. I think the issue is the HTML itself, rather than how it is being added to Outlook.. I have the same issue on Windows Live Mail too.

Comment: I guess that related how you building a signature. In past I had also build a signature using HTML and CSS and used in outlook 2010, and I never faced this kind of problem.

Comment: Well is there a way of stopping anything wrapping/floating to the right of a <table> element?

Comment: Fixed - I had to nest tables.

Surrounded my signature table with a `<table><tr><td width="100%"> ... </tr></td></table>`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and realized I had caused it by using the

```html
<table align="left">
```

command, forcing the quoted e-mail to appear to the right of my signature table.  Once I removed the align command it worked perfectly, without using nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I've selected the full signature in word document:

Right click > Table Properties> Text Wrapping> None.

This moves the original message below the signature as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `width` is set to `100%` for each `<table>` element (assuming you have two separate tables aligned vertically and not nested).

If setting tables width in MS Word didn't help, then edit your signature `.htm` file located under `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures` for Windows, by assigning `table` width to `100%`.